# The package version does not appear to be updating when importing locally with pipenv, even when in editable (developer) mode

Tags: setup.py, pipenv, distutils, python-packaging

I have written a small python package on my machine and made it importable with distutils. My `setup.py` has `version='0.0.3'`.

In a separate folder, I have a Pipenv environment and I install the package with the command:

```
pipenv install -e ~/path/to/my_pack
```

I then get the version with the commands:

```
pipenv run python
>> import pkg_resources  # part of setuptools
>> version = pkg_resources.require("my_pack")[0].version
>> print(version)
0.0.3
>> exit()
```

Next, I change the version in `setup.py` to `0.0.4` and run the above Python again, but it still says `0.0.3`. Why is this? How can I fix it?

If I add functions inside the `my_pack` code base, I can see them when I restart Python, but the version never changes.

Comment: As far as I know, there is nothing to fix, this is normal behavior, for changes to the package metadata you need to re-run the (editable) install command: `pipenv install -e ~/path/to/my_pack`.

Comment: @sinoroc do I need to `pipenv uninstall` before this or can I fix with just the one liner you gave?

Comment: I would assume that there is no need to uninstall ind simply re-installing (as editable) should be sufficient.